# Is Left 4 Dead's single-player mode tedious?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I'm wondering: what is playing Left 4 Dead in single-player mode like? Will it work with the AI? Does it quickly become tedious?

Comment: Could you try clarifying what exactly it is that you're asking?  And are you asking about Left4Dead, or Left4Dead 2?

Comment: I would add the need to clarify the question. One person's tedious is another's fun. What do you find tedious and what do you find fun? I suggest rewording your question so it can be answered with a little more definitive answer instead of just want opinions are out there.
All I can say is that many players continue to play single player after the game having been out for a long time (relatively). So either it isn't, or it is still fun despite it. What that means to you I can't tell.
UPDATE: Why are you asking about this mode? No internet access? Some reason you can only play this mode? Etc.

Answer (score 11):

**In short:** it quickly becomes tedious.

The AI is only suitable for Easy or Normal single player. Beating Advanced and Expert usually comes from team tactics as opposed to FPS skill, and tactics requires human cooperation. You'll find yourself constantly losing if you're using AI on those difficulties.

The AI has some other shortcomings. They are incapable of throwing grenades, meaning your team's stock of weapons is less than that of a human team. Also, they will heal you if you're hurt, *no matter the situation*. If this happens to you when it's crucial that you run as opposed to stop and heal, then keep a medkit on you and pull it out to prevent the AI from attempting to heal you.

Comment: I would suggest you point to the relation to Versus games and the necessity to have gone through all campaigns with bots or human co-op players at least on normal difficulty.

Comment: However, I believe you have to go through the campaign on advanced with a human before you play versus, but that's just my opinion. Is it really suitable in an answer? I'm sure he'll read your comment if you put it right under his question.

Comment: One answer to rule them all, I would say ;)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of whether it is tedious. It just points out some benefits/flaws of the buddy AI system. Killing zombies and surviving is the goal of that mode. The question asks if that goal is tedious or not.

Comment: I think it's clear that it's tedious to do with AI because of their shortcomings. Any suggestions for things to mention?

Comment: You can briefly stop a survivor healing you by switching to medpack or pills.

Answer (score 2):

AI behavior is correct, but sometimes they aren't fast enough to react... it totally depends on the situation.

You can either win or die, without being able to understand why they didn't help you...

The harder the game mode, the more the AI will fail... =)

Answer (score 1):

Left-4-Dead has pretty decent A.I.  Better than most games.  Generally, they'll stay with you, and provide decent support.  They rarely get *stuck* somewhere in the level, and will run away when you run away.  They will also almost always come to your aid if you need it.

That being said, they certainly aren't perfect, but nonetheless, I find that they're decent enough to warrant playing the game single-player.

Answer (score 0):

One thing not mentioned is that the game director makes the game unpredictable. You will sort of know what is coming in certain situations, but this game is different than all other SP games in that you are never really sure *exactly when* something bad is about to happen.

I know you asked about SP, but if you have access to internet, this game is well worth playing coop mode. There are always griefers, but you can make friends-only games and add people to your friends list who play nice.

Versus is a whole other game.

Comment: Agree that it's generally better to play this online.  I've found people are generally friendlier when you play on advanced or expert too.

Comment: The director does not make the game unpredictable. Playing expert realism recently we noticed the director consistently throwing a horde out at certain locations. We've never been caught off-guard by a horde since. The specials are only unpredictable in which ones are randomly selected. Other than that their behaviour is straightforward.

Comment: If you're capable of winning at expert, you probably won't be caught off-guard by anything anymore. This is where versus comes into play.